# Saving core data entities on a server

Tags: iphone, core-data

How would one save core data entities on a server?

If a phone creates the core data objects, how can they be saved if sent to the server?

Is it more efficient to send the data to the server and have the server save the core data objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [RESTKit](http://restkit.org)

Answer (score 1):

That's not really a feature of core data as it exists today. Core data is primarly a object graph layer that can persist to permanent storage (such as xml or sqlite). The objects (instances of NSManagedObject) are only valid within the context that they are created in (they are not even thread safe).

To send the objects to another server would invole you having to serialize the object, package it up for transmittion to your server, and then de-serialize the objects on your server side (they really wouldn't be instances of the same object though, you would just be coppying over the important properties that are relevant to your application).

To get the objects into some kind of userful state on your server you would most likely have to create new Entity instances in your server context.

From my perspective, I can't see the advantage of this at all unless some CORBA like behaviour was provided by Apple for Core Data in general. And I'd put thread safe NSManagedObject's up higher than that (whithout having to get involved in passing objectID's around between threads).